# Why isn't Firefox 33 use GCM on our webserver?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, firefox, ssl

We have a webserver (Ubuntu 12.04) with apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7.

From client side with openssl:

```
$ echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect OURSERVER:8080 2>/dev/null | egrep "Cipher is|Protocol"
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
$
```

we can connect OK, but our Firefox 33 under Ubuntu 14.04 can only connect max with:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

But when we visit other sites with the same Firefox 33, we can see it can use GCM!

**Question:** Why couldn't we connect with GCM to our webserver? Why isn't Firefox using ex.: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256?

Our apache config looks like this:

```
SSLCipherSuite "HIGH"
SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

Answer (score 0):

The "cipher suite" `HIGH` is a group of cipher suites. Apparently you have a different expectation of the ordering of these cipher suites than the defaults.

As you can see in the following output of the `openssl ciphers` command, the `DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256` cipher suite is preferred over the GCM cipher suite you are expecting.

```
$ openssl ciphers -V HIGH | \
> grep -nC1 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256\|ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256' | column -t
11-  0x00,0x9F  -  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2  Kx=DH    Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(256)  Mac=AEAD
12:  0x00,0x6B  -  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256          TLSv1.2  Kx=DH    Au=RSA    Enc=AES(256)     Mac=SHA256
13-  0x00,0x6A  -  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256          TLSv1.2  Kx=DH    Au=DSS    Enc=AES(256)     Mac=SHA256
--
33-  0x00,0x8D  -  PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA             SSLv3    Kx=PSK   Au=PSK    Enc=AES(256)     Mac=SHA1
34:  0xC0,0x2F  -  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256    TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH  Au=RSA    Enc=AESGCM(128)  Mac=AEAD
35-  0xC0,0x2B  -  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256  TLSv1.2  Kx=ECDH  Au=ECDSA  Enc=AESGCM(128)  Mac=AEAD
```

If you would like to force a particular order, explicitly specify the suites explicitly, as in:

```
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+AESGCM+AES128 EECDH+AESGCM DH+AESGCM+AES128 DH+AESGCM+AES EECDH+AES128 EECDH+AES DH+AES128 DH+AES RSA+AESGCM+AES128 RSA+AESGCM+AES RSA+AES128 RSA+AES RSA+3DES !MD5:!aNULL"
```

Note that your Apache version is [**too old**](https://community.qualys.com/message/19560#19560) to support ECDH cipher suites. Additionally, by using `SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1`, you will exclude the use of TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 in newer versions of Apache. I suggest to use `SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3` instead and upgrade your web server.

For reference, here is the [TestSSLServer](http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) output I obtained for Apache 2.22 running on Ubuntu 12.04 with `SSLCipherSuite HIGH` and `SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3`:

```
Supported versions: TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
Deflate compression: no
Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
  TLSv1.0
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
  (TLSv1.1: idem)
  TLSv1.2
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     DH_anon_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
----------------------
Server certificate(s):
  d975495633785b152215100eb449c57bee391e98: CN=ubuntu
----------------------
Minimal encryption strength:     strong encryption (96-bit or more)
Achievable encryption strength:  strong encryption (96-bit or more)
BEAST status: vulnerable
CRIME status: protected
```